# What is best practice regarding Interface organisation Visual Studio projects?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Single file for all interfaces or one file per interface definition?

Balena & Dimauro's of book of 'Pratical Guidelines' advocates a single file called Interfaces.vb/cs to hold all interface definitions. Their aim is to minimise the proliferation of small files, where each holds a single interface definition.

I can see benefits to both approaches. Does anyone have any strong views or experience that strongly supports one approach?

Comment: What does Balena & Dimauro say are the cons of having a lot of small files? [Curious]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, its better to have them in a separate file specially if your solution is in source control. If you have multiple check outs disabled in your source control then only one developer can work on one file/interface. Also you can compare what has been checked in against each interface, instead of looking at the difference of files. 
If you have a interface which is only implemented in one class, then I would rather have both of them in a same file.

Answer (score 3):

Well you said it yourself - each approach has its pros and cons. However, to make a decision easier, I'd say this:

If you develop only a small application (let's say max 10 interfaces), you can use single file if you want and be happy about it.

However, if you develop a larger application that will need to scale over time, use multiple files. It's certainly easier to maintain that way.

Well at least this is my opinion. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Both answers were useful in guiding my approach.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio you can have one file with multiple classes or interfaces. In Solution explorer the file would expand much like a tree view, to expose all classes/Interfaces in the file.

My preference would be to have all Interfaces under the same namespace in a single file. In other words group them by NameSpace in a single file.